# AAD App Registrations on Microsoft Graph

Tags: json, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating an app registration for Azure AD using my admin account. I intend to create an organization app registration (not multitenant).

When I create this manually via the Azure Portal, the app shows as it should.
But when I create it through the Microsoft Graph (POST /beta/applications), it does not show up in the portal. BUT it shows up when listing applications (GET /beta/applications). So it is clearly registered, but not showing in the portal.

What am I missing?

I am using the same user in code that I'm using logged in to the portal. When I look at the JSON result in te GET app list, the only differences is that the app created manually has the following properties:

```
"orgRestrictions": ["my-tenant-id-guid"],
"publisherDomain": null,
"api": {
    "acceptedAccessTokenVersion": null,
    ...
}
```

...and the app I created from code has these properties instead:

```
"orgRestrictions": [],
"publisherDomain": "mydomain.com",
"api": {
    "acceptedAccessTokenVersion": 2,
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API currently creates apps for the Azure AD "v2" endpoint. You should be able to see it if you sign in to https://apps.dev.microsoft.com (with the same account used to register the app via the API, of course).

Comment: Thank you, Philippe :-) That seems to be correct, the app is indeed visible on apps dev. Follow-up question, is there any way of creating an app that is also visible in the AAD blade of the Azure portal?

Comment: If you create an Application object with the Azure AD Graph API (rather than Microsoft Graph), it'll be a "v1 app", which you'll see in the Azure portal. Eventually these will be one and the same.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret In my program, when I register an application it is being registered using another app's credentials, not my own or any other person's. Is there any way to see these apps in azure ad on portal.azure.com? I know the apps are being created somewhere, because I get a response back.

Comment: @JaySchauer Could you elaborate on how exactly you are registering your apps? It is probably best to ask this (with all the details) in a separate question.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret ok, I will tag you

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775883/where-can-i-view-azure-ad-apps-created-through-microsoft-graph-beta-api