# Where can I view in a GUI Azure AD apps created through Microsoft Graph beta API and posted using user-less authentication?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The Microsoft Graph beta API [(here)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application) allows us to POST new applications to Azure AD (v2.0).

If I post these applications to a specific tenant, using a url like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/{tenantId}/applications
```

[and also authenticated without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service), where can I view these applications? They certainly aren't on my [apps.dev.microsoft.com](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) page (I checked), and they also aren't in the list of registered applications in the tenant on [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com)

PS: I know my applications are being created because I can call GET against that url and it will return the applications in that tenant, including the ones I created through the API. Also don't question why I was doing this, I was poking around figuring some stuff out about the API.

More Details: The app that is posting these applications to the beta API is registered as an Azure AD v1.0 app in the same tenant these applications are being posted to. The POSTs use the app's authentication token.

I know that apps created in portal.azure are v1 apps, and apps created on apps.dev.microsoft are v2 apps. I am making my apps through the Microsoft Graph beta API, which makes v2 apps.

Also, for those that don't click the link to see what authentication without a user means, I am getting the bearer token for the POST request using the app's credentials, not a user's credentials.

Answer (score 2):

> If I post these applications to a specific tenant (which is an Azure
>   AD v1.0 tenant), using a url like this

Here there is no version definition for the tenant. V1.0 and V2.0 are the endpoints, not means tenant. You could know about their difference from [Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview)and [v1 and v2 comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison).

If you register the app in the Azure portal, the app is v1 app; if you register the app by using App Registration Portal, the app is v2 app.

> and also authenticated without a user, where can I view these
>   applications? They certainly aren't on my apps.dev.microsoft.com page,
>   and they also aren't in the list of registered applications in the
>   tenant on portal.azure.com

If you create the app in the App Registration Portal, the app could be seen in the apps.dev.microsoft.com page(App Registration Portal), but cannot be seen in the Azure portal.

If you create the app is v1 app, the app can be seen both in Azure portal and App Registration Portal.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me about the tenants. Also, you didn't really answer my question. I am not making the apps through any portal, I am making them through the Microsoft Graph API. Another user says that apps made through the api are v2 apps. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50652575/5096422